# Could not resolve placeholder 'HOSTNAME' in value "${HOSTNAME}.eureka

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, minikube, netflix-eureka

## This is my deploymentservice.yaml(Kubernetes) file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eureka-cm
data:
  eureka_service_address: http://eureka-0.eureka:8761/eureka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      name: eureka
  selector:
    app: eureka

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: eureka
spec:
  serviceName: "eureka"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eureka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eureka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eureka
          image: firozehossain01/gieurekaserver:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8761
          env:
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eureka-lb
  labels:
    app: eureka
spec:
  selector:
    app: eureka
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8761
```

## application.yml(Spring Boot Application)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: "${HOSTNAME}.eureka"
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS}
```

## But When I run this with Jenkins... This shows

```
Factory method 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'HOSTNAME' in value "${HOSTNAME}.eureka"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'HOSTNAME' in value "${HOSTNAME}.eureka"
```

## Here I mention That

```
I am using Minikube for Kubernetes Cluster, Docker Desktop, Windows OS, CI/CD(Jenkins), Spring Boot Micro-Services.
```

***Can Any one help me to solve this issue?***

Why spring boot application does not know the hostname with value of kubernetes service? I want to run the kubernetes services with local/development environment with the help of mminikube with kube forwarding.

Comment: In pod, does environment variables contains`HOSTNAME` value ?

Comment: I've successfully resolved the issue. I've implemented a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins, but I discovered a minor error in the Kubernetes configuration. Specifically, I failed to specify the environment path correctly for the StatefulSet, which is something I usually do when working with Deployment configurations in Jenkins.